# Akka http request does not trace through opentelemetry

Tags: scala, akka-http, open-telemetry, javaagents, jaeger

I am trying to use opentelemtry (OTEL) in akka-http application (Scala), using the stand alone agent.
In my sbt I have this:

```
fork := true

run / javaOptions ++= Seq(
  "-XX:+UseG1GC",
  "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100",
  "-XX:+PrintGCDetails",
  "-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution",
  "-XX:+PrintGCCause",
  "-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy",
  "-javaagent:/myFolder/jars/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar",
  "-Dotel.service.name=pantryLocalExecution",
  "-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp",
  "-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp",
)
envVars += "OTEL_JAVA_GLOBAL_AUTOCONFIGURE_ENABLED" -> "true"
```

I am using Jeager to watch all metrics that OTEL collects, then thing is, Jeager is not showing Http request, only mysql connections.
Addition to that, is not grouping the flow into the same trace, Next image show what I mean. There are 3 traces which are the same flow.

[image]

Thank you all for all your help!!

Quick notes:

- I am sure that the agent path is ok.
- Before use Jaeger UI i needed to run docker command:
  ** `docker run -d --name jaeger \\n  -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT=:9411 \\n  -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true \\n  -p 6831:6831/udp \\n  -p 6832:6832/udp \\n  -p 5778:5778 \\n  -p 16686:16686 \\n  -p 4317:4317 \\n  -p 4318:4318 \\n  -p 14250:14250 \\n  -p 14268:14268 \\n  -p 14269:14269 \\n  -p 9411:9411 \\n  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.42\`
- Finally I run using sbt run command.

Comment: It works, I created another small app and it worked, I am still working to find the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding and finding and creating small projects with different versions, I discovered that OTEL only works as I want (The same flow with child spans), only is necessary 10.2.0-RC2 version of akka or higher.
Just keep in mind all the settings that I posted!

Thank you all!!